# Getting previous folder name with makefile

Tags: gnu-make

My directory structure looks like this:

```
root_folder/
  --main_folder/  
    |-- build_and_run.c     
    |-- build_and_run     
    -- sub_folder/
       |-- makefile
       |-- your_program.c
```

I want the `make-file` to get the name of the main_folder.

I've tried:

```
$(shell dirname $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
$(basename $(dirname `pwd`))
```

without success.

I'm working on PowerShell terminal, and I'm a beginner when it comes to makefile syntax.

Comment: Please show exactly what you tried, with proper formatting, and what the result was.  Making a small example makefile to show the problem will allow us to pinpoint what's wrong.  You don't need to use `shell` at all; GNU Make has enough built-in functions to manipulate filenames.